# How to efficiently store similar SQL queries for API execution

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm writing an API in Flask which loads queries saved in files to execute them.  The query executed depends on the input format.  However, all the queries are the same except they may have 1 of these 4 snippets:

```
SELECT *
FROM shipments
WHERE origin = %(origin)s
AND destination = %(destination)s

SELECT *
FROM shipments
WHERE origin = %(origin)s
AND destination IN %(destination)s

SELECT *
FROM shipments
WHERE origin IN %(origin)s
AND destination = %(destination)s

SELECT *
FROM shipments
WHERE origin IN %(origin)s
AND destination IN %(destination)s
```

Is there a better way to save & modify a single SQL query based on the input format, rather than having 4 slightly different copies?

I'm unsure if this is even desirable since they *are* 4 different queries, but I was wondering if there's a way to parameterize the query itself like:

```
SELECT *
FROM shipments
WHERE origin %(origin_format)q %(origin)s
AND destination %(destination_format)q %(destination)s
```

Where `%(origin_format)q` and `%(destination_format)q` would be `IN` or `=`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: To reduce the 4 queries to 1, each snippet now looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM shipments
WHERE origin {orig_in_or_equals} %(origin)s
AND destination {dest_in_or_equals} %(destination)s
```

The application then:

1. Reads the query
2. Converts the bytes to string
3. Replaces `{orig_in_or_equals}` and `{dest_in_or_equals}` with `IN` or `=` as needed
4. Converts the string back into bytes

Then the query is executed with its parameters as usual.